# Error : Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

me salió este error en el Listado de turnos esto ocurrió cuando borre un paciente que tenia varios registros en el apartado de turnos, no se como lo podría solucionar, si me podrían dar una manito. Muchísimas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del error:

```
  public static function obtenerPorId($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT paciente.id_obrasocial, persona.id_persona, persona.nombre, persona.apellido, persona.dni, "
         . "persona.fecha_nacimiento, persona.estado, persona.id_sexo, paciente.id_paciente, paciente.id_obrasocial, "
         . "paciente.fecha_alta " 
         . "FROM paciente "
         . "JOIN persona ON persona.id_persona = paciente.id_persona "
         . "JOIN sexo ON sexo.id_sexo = persona.id_sexo "
         . "WHERE id_paciente = {$id} and paciente.estado= 1";
    //echo $sql;
    $database = new mysql();
    $datos = $database->consultar($sql);

    if($datos == false){ 
        return false;
    }

    $registro = $datos->fetch_assoc();
    $paciente = self::_crearPaciente($registro);
    return $paciente;
}

private static function _crearPaciente($datos) {
    $paciente = new Paciente();
    $paciente->_idPaciente = $datos["id_paciente"];  //DESDE ACA ME TIRA EL ERROR
    $paciente->_idPersona = $datos["id_persona"];
    $paciente->_nombre = $datos["nombre"];
    $paciente->_apellido = $datos["apellido"];
    $paciente->_dni = $datos["dni"];
    $paciente->_estado = $datos["estado"];
    $paciente->_fechaNacimiento = $datos["fecha_nacimiento"];
    $paciente->_fechaalta = $datos["fecha_alta"];
    $paciente->_idSexo = $datos["id_sexo"];
    $paciente->_idObraSocial = $datos["id_obrasocial"];
    return $paciente;
}
```

Comment: La variable `$registro` es `null`, lo que significa que no existe un paciente con `id_paciente = $id` y `estado = 1`. Antes de llamar a `_crearPaciente` deberías chequear la variable `$registro`

Comment: Cuando eliminas un registro de una tabla que tiene valores en campos relacionados con otras tablas debes corregir las otras tablas tambien. Lo que te han dicho está bien para eliminar el error que se muestra, pero lo más correcto es localizar los registros huérfanos de las otras tablas y modificarlos o eliminarlos segun te convenga. Aprende a usar la integridad referencial y tu base de datos será mucho más sólida en ese aspecto.